# Geofence when app is killed on Android Oreo

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-8.0-oreo, android-geofence, android-workmanager

I'm creating a location based app which gets the current location of the user every 'x' minutes in the background, for that I'm planning to use PeriodicWorkRequest using WorkManager API.

1. But the thing is the minimum time for repeat interval is 15 minutes, so I thought I could use this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o) (which uses Broadcast receiver in the pending intent) to get user's location updates, Which of the methods should I be using?
2. I'm planning to get Latitude and longitude coordinates from an API and create a Geofence with that latitude and longitude using Periodic Work Request Every 15 minutes in the Background, But the thing is I have Android Oreo and my Geofence does not seem to be triggered or I do not get any notification when my App is killed, I only get when app is in background or in the foreground even after I'm using Broadcast receiver for the pending intent in creating Geofence.
3. Also my periodic work does not seem to run as expected, because I Have put a test notification in the work and it gets executed only when I open the app for the first time and does not work after 15 minutes as it is expected to work, My Main Goal is to Create a periodic work request which runs every 15 minutes in the background, downloads location data from API and creates a geofence with that location, but since my work manager and geofence is not working properly I'm not able to achieve desired results. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the Code I'm using.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.rohit.geofencefundo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final int LOC_PERM_REQ_CODE = 1;
    //meters
    private static final int GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 150;
    //in milli seconds
    private static final int GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION = 600000;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    android.location.LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng userLocation;
    Data data;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






       /* geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
        showCurrentLocationOnMap();*/


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.g_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        //addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        data = new Data.Builder()
                .putString(BackgroundWork.EXTRA_TITLE, "Message from Activity!")
                .putString(BackgroundWork.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi! I have come from activity.")
                .build();


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15);

        showCurrentLocationOnMap();
        //locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoCheckBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWork.class, 15,
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .addTag("notifWorker");
// ...if you want, you can apply constraints to the builder here...

// Create the actual work object:
        PeriodicWorkRequest photoCheckWork = photoCheckBuilder.setInputData(data).build();
// Then enqueue the recurring task:
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(photoCheckWork);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                addLocationAlert(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void showCurrentLocationOnMap() {
        if (isLocationAccessPermitted()) {
            requestLocationAccessPermission();
        } else if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    /*public void addFence(View view){

        addLocationAlert(28.360596,75.5863917); //28.360596 75.5863917  budh bhavan
        addLocationAlert( 28.3603219,75.5868534); //ram marg

    }*/






    /*@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void showCurrentLocationOnMap() {
        if (isLocationAccessPermitted()) {
            requestLocationAccessPermission();
        }
    }*/

    private boolean isLocationAccessPermitted() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestLocationAccessPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                LOC_PERM_REQ_CODE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void addLocationAlert(double lat, double lng) {
        if (isLocationAccessPermitted()) {
            requestLocationAccessPermission();
        } else {
            String key = "" + lat + "-" + lng;
            Geofence geofence = getGeofence(lat, lng, key);
           /* geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(geofence),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Location alter has been added",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Location alter could not be added",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });*/


            geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(geofence),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    });


        }
    }

    private void removeLocationAlert() {
        if (isLocationAccessPermitted()) {
            requestLocationAccessPermission();
        } else {

            geofencingClient.removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Location alters have been removed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Location alters could not be removed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOC_PERM_REQ_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    showCurrentLocationOnMap();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Location access permission granted, you try " +
                                    "add or remove location allerts",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }


    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationAlertBroadcastReceiver.class);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL);
        builder.addGeofence(geofence);
        return builder.build();
    }

    private Geofence getGeofence(double lat, double lang, String key) {
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(key)
                .setCircularRegion(lat, lang, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .setLoiteringDelay(10000)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.remove_loc_alert:
                removeLocationAlert();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }


}
```

GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService:

```
package com.example.rohit.geofencefundo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 573;

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

    /**
     * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
     */
    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionInfo(
                    triggeringGeofences);
            String transitionType = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);


            sendNotification(transitionType, geofenceTransitionDetails);
            sendNotification2(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
    private String getGeofenceTransitionInfo(List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        ArrayList<String> locationNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            locationNames.add(getLocationName(geofence.getRequestId()));
        }
        String triggeringLocationsString = TextUtils.join(", ", locationNames);

        return triggeringLocationsString;
    }
    private String getLocationNameGeocoder(double lat, double lng) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng, 1);
        } catch (Exception ioException) {
            Log.e("", "Error in getting location name for the location");
        }

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            Log.d("", "no location name");
            return null;
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                addressInfo.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }

            return TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressInfo);
        }
    }
    private String getLocationName(String key) {
        String[] strs = key.split("-");

        String locationName = null;
        if (strs != null && strs.length == 2) {
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(strs[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(strs[1]);

            locationName = getLocationNameGeocoder(lat, lng);
        }
        if (locationName != null) {
            return locationName;
        } else {
            return key;
        }
    }


    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }


    private void sendNotification(String locTransitionType, String locationDetails) {



        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "rohit901";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"My Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("rohit901 channel for app test FCM");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(android.support.compat.R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setContentTitle(locTransitionType)
                .setContentText(locationDetails)
                .setContentInfo("info");

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        m += random.nextInt(100) + 1;

        notificationManager.notify(m,notificationBuilder.build());



    }




    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL:
                return "dwell at location";
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }
}
```

Background Work (Worker Class):

```
package com.example.rohit.geofencefundo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import androidx.work.Data;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class BackgroundWork extends Worker {
    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE = "output_message";
    JSONObject jsonPart;
    String result;
    private Context mContext;
    public BackgroundWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        //do work and shit
        Log.d("work901","work and shit");
        String title = getInputData().getString(EXTRA_TITLE);
        String text = getInputData().getString(EXTRA_TEXT);
        Log.d("work901tit","title from main is "+title);
        Data output = new Data.Builder()
                .putString(EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, "I have come from MyWorker!")
                .build();



        sendNotification(title,text);
        new JsonTask().execute("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2018-10-20&endtime=2018-10-21&latitude=33.9370804&longitude=135.8284085&maxradiuskm=5000");





        setOutputData(output);
        return Result.SUCCESS;

    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String text) {



        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "rohit901";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"My Notification",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("rohit901 channel for app test FCM");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(android.support.compat.R.drawable.notification_icon_background)
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentInfo("info");

        Random random = new Random();
        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        m += random.nextInt(100) + 1;

        notificationManager.notify(m,notificationBuilder.build());



    }
    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {







        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE LOADING FEEDS

            //pd.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);


            //Toast.makeText(FeedBackActivity.this, "DOne", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("rohit901",s);
            result = s;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                String features = jsonObject.getString("features"); //array of features
                //JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(features);
                //String geometry = jsonObject2.getString("geometry"); //array of geometry
                //JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject(geometry);
                //String coordinates = jsonObject3.getString("coordinates");
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(features);
                JSONArray locArr;

                Log.d("work901Array",arr.toString());


                for(int i =0;i<arr.length();i++) {





                    jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    //jsonPart2 =
                    locArr = new JSONArray(jsonPart.getJSONObject("geometry").getString("coordinates"));
                    Log.d("geo901","Longitude: "+locArr.getString(0)+", Latitude: "+locArr.getString(1));

                }





            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();


                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line+"\n");
                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

                }

                return buffer.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;


        }
    }
}
```

Rest of my code is here: [GitHub](https://github.com/rohit901/GeoFenceFunDo)

Comment: Worker is working fine on android 9,called every 15 minutes

Comment: each time i run my app the worker again gets started and since I'm not cancelling my worker currently will it run for infinite period of time and will multiple worker be started depending on number of times i run my app? then OS may kill the backgground process thinking it consumes a lot of battery

Comment: you can try enqueueUniquePeriodicWork() this method , it will  handle duplicate worker request based on ExistingPolicy parameter passed to that method.

Comment: Hi vishal, thanks for commenting but it seems that the background work is not working as expected in my android oreo, I ran the app once and then got the background worker notification as expected now it has been 18+ minutes yet no notification, refer the pic: https://ibb.co/dSWDFq

Comment: I just realized that when i open the app for a long time i see that there are lot of notifications from the app, I'm probably guessing that's from the worker class but it failed to send while the app was in background or when killed so do you have any idea on how I can make the notification work properly even when app is in background or killed state? currently only when i open the app again it sends me notification i guess.

Comment: @RohitBharadwaj Did you find any solution for this Geofencing issue? Now, i'm also facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActivityExpenseDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("employee_name",expenseArrayList.get(position).getEmployee_name());
            intent.putExtra("expense_type",expenseArrayList.get(position).getExpense_type());
            intent.putExtra("amount",expenseArrayList.get(position).getAmount());
            intent.putExtra("description",expenseArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```